# Fetch instagram user media with API Token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

1. I've checked many resources, and most of them claim the only way to fetch users media using an token is to create facebook app, add instagram, generate user token for yourself and fetch graph api. `https://graph.instagram.com/me` endpoint. Is there no other way to simply fetch user's media via official api by using access token and username?

Also, when I use `/me` endpoint, everything works. If I change it to `/*myusername*`, where I obviously put my username instead, it says that said object `does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no. If you want to use Instagram API to fetch regular( ie not business ) users' feed, you need to use Instagram Basic API.